# How to Create a Touchpoint Table from a list

Tags: sql, dataframe, data-analysis, data-manipulation, databricks-sql

I am working on a SQL query in the Azure Databricks environment that has the following dataset:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE touchpoints_table
(
  List  STRING,
  Path_Lenght INT
);

INSERT INTO touchpoints_table VALUES
  ('BBB, AAA, CCC', 3),  
  ('BBB', 1),
  ('DDD, AAA', 2), 
  ('DDD, BBB, AAA, EEE, CCC', 5), 
  ('EEE, AAA, EEE, CCC', 4);
  
SELECT * FROM touchpoints_table
```

```
|     |             List           |   Path_length   | 
|  0  | BBB, AAA, CCC              |       3         |  
|  1  | CCC                        |       1         |   
|  2  | DDD, AAA                   |       2         |   
|  3  | DDD, BBB, AAA, EEE, CCC    |       5         |  
|  4  | EEE, AAA, EEE, CCC         |       4         |
```

and the task consists of generating the following table:

```
|     |   Content       |   Unique    |  Started  |  Middleway  |  Finished  |
|  0  |     AAA         |     0       |     0     |      3      |      1     | 
|  1  |     BBB         |     0       |     1     |      1      |      0     |
|  2  |     CCC         |     1       |     0     |      0      |      3     |
|  3  |     DDD         |     0       |     2     |      0      |      0     |
|  4  |     EEE         |     0       |     1     |      2      |      0     |
```

where the columns contain the following:

- **Content**: the elements found in the **List**
- **Unique**: the number of times that the element appears alone in the list
- **Started**: the number of times that the element appears at the beginning
- **Finished**: the number of times that the element appears at the end
- **Middleway**: the number of times the element appears between the beginning and the end.

Using the following query I almost get the result but somehow the group by does not worked correctly

```
WITH tb1 AS(
  SELECT 
    CAST(touch_array AS STRING) AS touch_list,
    EXPLODE(touch_array) AS explode_list,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(touch_array AS STRING) ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) touch_count,
    COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY touch_array) touch_lenght
  FROM (SELECT SPLIT(List, ',') AS touch_array FROM touchpoints_table) 
  )
  SELECT
     explode_list AS Content,
     SUM(CASE WHEN touch_lenght=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unique,
     SUM(CASE WHEN touch_count=1 AND touch_lenght > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Started,
     SUM(CASE WHEN touch_count>1 AND touch_count < touch_lenght THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Middleway,
     SUM(CASE WHEN touch_count>1 AND touch_count = touch_lenght THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finished  
  FROM tb1 
  GROUP BY explode_list
  ORDER BY explode_list
```

```
|     |   Content       |   Unique    |  Started  |  Middleway  |  Finished  |
|  0  |     AAA         |     0       |     0     |      3      |      1     | 
|  1  |     BBB         |     0       |     0     |      1      |      0     |
|  2  |     CCC         |     0       |     0     |      0      |      3     |
|  3  |     EEE         |     0       |     0     |      2      |      0     |
|  4  |     BBB         |     1       |     1     |      0      |      0     |
|  5  |     DDD         |     0       |     2     |      0      |      0     |
|  6  |     EEE         |     0       |     1     |      0      |      0     |
```

Could you help me by suggesting a code that solves this task?

Answer (score 1):

Query example for SQL Server

```
with allElements as(
  select list ,el,elN,elQty
  from touchpoints_table tp 
  cross apply (select trim(value) as el,row_number()over(order by (select 1)) elN 
                ,count(*)over() elQty
                from string_split(tp.list,',')
              ) t
)
select el
   ,sum(case when elQty=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'unique'
   ,sum(case when elN=1 and elQty>1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'strated'
   ,sum(case when elN>1 and elN<elQty then 1 else 0 end) as 'middleway'
   ,sum(case when elN>1 and elN=elQty then 1 else 0 end) as 'finished'
from allElements
group by el
order by el
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jNgQ__F6)

Comment: I tried to write your code for the Databricks SQL, but I had a problem with the group by, do you know what could be wrong with my query? I updated the question.

Comment: I would like to test the hypothesis: Splitting list like ''DDD, BBB, AAA, EEE, CCC'  and 'BBB, AAA, CCC'

Comment: explode list :'DDD',' BBB',' AAA',' EEE',' CCC','BBB' . Delete (trim) spaces. https://dbfiddle.uk/2JJfKZxY

Comment: maybe it is enough to replace EXPLODE(touch_array) by trim(BOTH FROM touch_array). Your touch_array has 1 element.